# Google Auth stopped working after 2 years

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've got the following code snippet:

```
// Google functions
var clientId = 'clientid';
var apiKey = 'apikey';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

function handleClientLoad() {
    // Step 2: Reference the API key
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    });
}

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    console.error(authResult.error);
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        if (!$('#authWait').is(':visible')) {
            $('#start').on("click", function () {
                $('#main').hide();
                $('#wizard').removeClass("hidden");
            });
        } else {
            $('#authWait').addClass("hidden");
            $('#wizard').removeClass("hidden");
        }
        fillCalendarList();
        ga('send', 'event', 'weergaveResultaat', 'action');
    } else {
        $('#start').on("click", function () {
            $('#main').hide();
            $('#authWait').removeClass("hidden");
            handleAuthClick();
        })
    }
}
```

I've replaced the clientid and apikey. The exact snippet above has been working for 2 years in the exact same configuration. As of yesterday however I'm getting back 'immediate failed' right after the `handleAuthResult`.

I couldn't find any details of changes Google made since yesterday. I've tried switching immediate to false, but that didn't solve anything.

After the immediate failed I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'apiVersion' of undefined'.

Anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: `immediate=true` stops working for me every 2 weeks (the returned auth has incorrect scopes). In my code I use try/catch and also check the scopes. If something is wrong, I call again with immediate=false.